# Check if differences between elements already exists in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, heuristics

I'm trying to build a heuristic for the simplest feasible [Golomb Ruler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_ruler) as possible. From 0 to n, find n numbers such that all the differences between them are different. This heuristic consists of incrementing the ruler by 1 every time. If a difference already exists on a list, jump to the next integer. So the ruler starts with [0,1] and the list of differences = [ 1 ]. Then we try to add 2 to the ruler [0,1,2], but it's not feasible, since the difference (2-1 = 1) already exists in the list of differences. Then we try to add 3 to the ruler [0,1,3] and it is feasible, and thus the list of differences becomes [1,2,3] and so on.  Here's what I've come to so far:

```
n = 5
positions = list(range(1,n+1))
Pos = []
Dist = []
difs = []
i = 0


while (i < len(positions)):
    if len(Pos)==0:
        Pos.append(0)
        Dist.append(0)
    elif len(Pos)==1:
            Pos.append(1)
            Dist.append(1)
    else:
        postest = Pos + [i] #check feasibility to enter the ruler
        difs = [a-b for a in postest for b in postest if a > b] 
        if any (d in difs for d in Dist)==True:
                pass
        else:
            for d in difs:
                Dist.append(d) 
            Pos.append(i) 
    i += 1
```

However I can't make the differences check to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For efficiency I would tend to use a set to store the differences, because they are good for inclusion testing, and you don't care about the ordering (possibly until you actually print them out, at which point you can use `sorted`).

You can use a temporary set to store the differences between the number that you are testing and the numbers you currently have, and then either add it to the existing set, or else discard it if you find any matches.  (Note `else` block on `for` loop, that will execute if `break` was not encountered.)

```
n = 5

i = 0
vals = []
diffs = set()
while len(vals) < n:
    diffs1 = set()
    for j in reversed(vals):
        diff = i - j
        if diff in diffs:
            break
        diffs1.add(diff)
    else:
        vals.append(i)
        diffs.update(diffs1)
    i += 1

print(vals, sorted(diffs))
```

The explicit loop over values (rather than the use of `any`) is to avoid unnecessarily calculating the differences between the candidate number and *all* the existing values, when most candidate numbers are not successful and the loop can be aborted early after finding the first match.

It would work for `vals` also to be a set and use `add` instead of `append` (although similarly, you would probably want to use `sorted` when printing it).  In this case a list is used, and although it does not matter in principle in which order you iterate over it, this code is iterating in reverse order to test the smaller differences first, because the likelihood is that unusable candidates are rejected more quickly this way.  Testing it with n=200, the code ran in about 0.2 seconds with `reversed` and about 2.1 without `reversed`; the effect is progressively more noticeable as `n` increases.  With n=400, it took 1.7 versus 27 seconds with and without the `reversed`.

Comment: That's great. It works fine and fast. Why in diffs |= diffs1 it's not possible to use diffs.add(diffs1)  ?

Comment: @fsimoyama Because you want to add every member of the set `diffs1`, you don't want to add the set as an element of `diffs` (and it is not permitted anyway to do that, because set elements must be immutable objects). The `diffs |= diffs1` could be replaced with `diffs = diffs.union(diffs1)` if that is clearer.

Comment: @fsimoyama Actually what I am doing here is generating a new set which is the union and am assigning it back to the name `diffs` and discarding the old set. It might perhaps be quicker (for sufficiently small set `diffs1` and sufficiently large set `diffs`) to loop over the elements of `diffs1` doing a `diffs.add()` on each element. I'll leave you to compare timings if you want to.

Comment: @fsimoyama Actually scratch that, it seems that sets have an `update` method that I had forgotten about. I'll change it to `diffs.update(diffs1)`.

Comment: @fsimoyama Now changed (and tested for functionality, although not timings). Think of `update` like the `extend` method on lists, though of course unordered. But it ought to be a faster equivalent of the explicit loop that I mentioned before I remembered about it - i.e. it adds elements to the existing set rather than creating a new one.